# Can't connect a azure sql server from laravel on linux

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, azure-sql-database, sqlsrv

I have a laravel application that connect a sql server db on Azure.

On my local Wamp server the application works.
I have installed on my linux server using a docker image, and don't connect the Azure DB.
Every time returns this error message:

```
SQLSTATE[HYT00]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (SQL: select * from [mytable])
```

MSDOBC Driver, sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv are correctly installed.

I suppose is something related with laravel because if I query the db with a php script works without problem.

My .ENV file has db settings:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=db.database.windows.net
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=db_name
DB_USERNAME=db_user
DB_PASSWORD=pwd
```

Laravel log and docker log don't tell nothing interesting, I don't have any idea how to solve.

Comment: "On my local Wamp server works": What's running on WAMP? The db server or the webserver?

Comment: Where does "db.database.windows.net" point to? Your docker container?

Comment: Is port 1433 open on the DB server?

Comment: The sql server is on Azure cloud. On WAMP there is the webserver (for development)

Comment: Yes the port 1433 is open, if I connect from my pc i connect without problem.
I tried set port=null and nothing changed.

Comment: SQL server driver is different in Linux, please ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15#installing-the-drivers-with-php-fpm-on-ubuntu and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I think my driver are installed correctly. I tried the sqltest.php script and the response is correct: "Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8 Jul 17 2020 00:35:17 Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Azure SQL Database supports only the tabular data stream (TDS) protocol (accessible over TCP and the default port of 1433) and uses its own IP-based firewall. So you may try the following:

- Use connection string with protocol, server name and port. In your case you need to use `tcp:db.database.windows.net,1433` as a value of `DB_HOST`.
- Add the IP address of your LINUX server as a firewall rule. This is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure#connections-from-the-internet):

> When a computer tries to connect to your server from the internet, the
> firewall first checks the originating IP address of the request
> against the database-level IP firewall rules for the database that the
> connection requests.
>
> If the address is within a range that's specified in the
> database-level IP firewall rules, the connection is granted to the
> database that contains the rule.
>
> - If the address isn't within a range in the database-level IP firewall rules, the firewall checks the server-level IP firewall
>   rules.
> - If the address is within a range that's in the server-level IP firewall rules, the connection is granted. Server-level IP firewall
>   rules apply to all databases managed by the server.
> - If the address isn't within a range that's in any of the database-level or server-level IP firewall rules, the connection
>   request fails

Comment: Thanks, the ip of linux server is in the firewall list (it works properly if connect directly with php test script)

Comment: Laravel version: 7.10.3

Comment: @cesare What is the result with `tcp:db.database.windows.net,1433` as a value of `DB_HOST`. I'm trying to find if `Laravel` can cause problems. `Laravel` simply creates a new `PDO` isntance using `sqlsrv` driver (but only if the driver is available) or a new  PDO instance using `dblib` driver. I assume, that `sqsrv` is available (source is in ``..\database\connectors\SqlServeConnector.php`).

Comment: with `tcp:db.database.windows.net,1433` is working!  Thanks, for your help. Please update the answer so I can accept the solution.

Comment: I'm facing the same error, this did not fix it for me. Still getting "Login failed for user ..."