mysqli trying to connect as username@ipaddress when i want it to connect as username@domain
I'm moving one of my developments from a local server to Azure. The database has already been moved, and I'm trying to get a version of my code in Azure to connect to the database. The issue I'm having is that Laravel defaults to sending the username as username@%the server's IP% rather than username@domain.
For example, I want it to send as admin@mysite.
It is self-generating this IP address, and none of my config is set to try to append this. This is an issue because to get the development working, we need to allow MySQL access for the account from a specific location, and we don't want to grant based on IP in case the IP address changes.
Here is my DB config file for MySQL:
'mysql' => [
'driver' => 'mysql',
'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
'prefix' => '',
'prefix_indexes' => true,
'strict' => false,
'engine' => null,
'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA', false),
]) : [],
],

My .env setting are as below ->
DB_DATABASE=access_statement
DB_USERNAME=acc_statement
DB_HOST=mysite.mysql.database.azure.com
DB_PORT=3306
DB_PASSWORD=password

Any help would be appreciated! I've already spent far too long trying to work this out.
I've tried hard setting the host, etc., rather than using environment variables, but still get this issue. I've also tried hard setting the user account to be admin@mysite, but this just means when I deploy the app it tries to parse the username as admin@mysite@ipaddress, which is never going to work!

Have a look at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63132295/cant-connect-a-azure-sql-server-from-laravel-on-linux.

Unfortunately, this is not how mysql works.
